# Caching java.util.Map with ehcache

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, ehcache

I'm using EHCache with Hibernate to cache my DB query results.
I'm using google annotations(`com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable`) to make DAO methods cacheable.

My problem is that, one of the argument in the method is a `java.util.Map` and I have no clue how to cache it?

Sample Code :

```
import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable;
import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.KeyGenerator;
import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.PartialCacheKey;
import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Property;
```

Here is the sample method

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "ehcahe", keyGenerator = @KeyGenerator(name = "HashCodeCacheKeyGenerator", properties = @Property(name = "includeMethod", value = "false")))
public Object get( @PartialCacheKey Map map ) {
 //do something
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own `CacheKeyGenerator` , See [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), Question 7